# Select with disabled attribute set as "disabled" still allows options to be selected on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cross-browser

I´m developing an application using Zend Framework 2 and I´m using two select boxes. 
The first is populated with data from the data base, the second is empty.

After clicking a button to pass the selected option from the **first Select** to the **second one** (via Javascript) I set the **disabled attribute** on the first select to **"disabled"** so that no other options can be selected and therefore passed to the second select.

```
  //Whithin javascript function  
  var s = document.getElementById('firstSelect');
  s.setAttribute("disabled","disabled");
```

Everything works fine on IE, Firefox and Safari (after passing one option from the first select to the other the first select is disabled and greyedout and you simply cannot select more options.) but **not on Chrome**.

The first select is greyed out like on all the other browsers but still allows the user to select another option and pass it to the other select box. After this happens no more options can be selected and it behaves like all the other browsers do.

Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Can you provide a complete reduced test case please? A live version on jsbin.com would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, chrome is right. You are selecting based on ID (*getElementById*). These **MUST** be unique in your DOM tree. So if you have multiple elements with the same ID Google selects just the one.

You now have two options:
 - extend your code to load elements either through *getElementsByClassname*, though this isn't very well supported yet IIRC, or use *getElementsByTagname*. this returns an array which you subsequently can loop through and set the attributes accordingly
 - get into jQuery (or any other framework) and have the framework solve this for you (most frameworks have functionality in place for precisely these type of situations ;))

Succsess..

ps: elements *CAN* have the same '*name*' attribute, that's not the same as '*id*'

Comment: hm.. maybe my question wasn´t clear enough. My select as an unique ID (id = "firstSelect"). So when you click on an option of this first select and then press a button to pass it to the other select a JS function tells that this firstSelect now has the disabled attribute set as disabled and therefor it shouldn´t allow the user to select more options.